# Returning boolean from arrow function in a react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to extract the business logic from my stateless functional components in React 16.2.

This works:

```
const Jobs = props => (
  props.entries
    .map(entry => (
      <Job
        entry={entry}
        isInitJobExpanded={
          entry.fields.project['en-US'] &&
          props.initJobExpanded &&
          (entry.fields.project['en-US'] === props.initJobExpanded)}
        key={entry.sys.id}
      />
    )));
```

And when I want to extract `isInitJobExpanded`, I've tried:

```
const isInitJobExpandedFunction = ({ entry, props }) => (
  entry.fields.project['en-US'] &&
  props.initJobExpanded &&
  entry.fields.project['en-US'] === props.initJobExpanded
);

const Jobs = props => (
  props
    .map(entry => (
      <Job
        entry={entry}
        isInitJobExpanded={isInitJobExpandedFunction}
        key={entry.sys.id}
      />
    )));
```

However, I get the error message:

```
Invalid prop `isInitJobExpanded` of type `function` supplied to `Job`, expected `boolean`.`
```

I've also tried:

```
isInitJobExpanded={this.isInitJobExpandedFunction}

isInitJobExpanded={this.isInitJobExpandedFunction()}

isInitJobExpanded={isInitJobExpandedFunction()}

isInitJobExpanded={() => isInitJobExpandedFunction}
```

etc

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `isInitJobExpanded={isInitJobExpandedFunction({entry, props)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isInitJobExpandedFunction` receive an object, that must have two fields: `entry` and `props`. So your code is:

```js
const isInitJobExpandedFunction = ({ entry, props }) => (
  entry.fields.project['en-US'] &&
  props.initJobExpanded &&
  entry.fields.project['en-US'] === props.initJobExpanded
);

const Jobs = props => (
  props
    .map(entry => (
      <Job
        entry={entry}
        isInitJobExpanded={isInitJobExpandedFunction({entry, props})}
        key={entry.sys.id}
      />
    )));
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to pass it with `{isInitJobExpandedFunction(entry, props)}` not `{isInitJobExpandedFunction({entry, props})}`. Is there a rule of thumb on when to pass it in curly braces or not with arrow functions?

Comment: It depends on the function declaration. 
You also can declare you arrow function as: `const isInitJobExpandedFunction = (entry, props) => {}` and call it without curly bracers: `isInitJobExpandedFunction(entry, props)`